# Postgresql: Identify events across multiple rows (power consumption)

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, iot, window-functions

I've got a Postgresql table that contains time series data of accumulated power usage and the actual current at a time. At the moment washing a washing machine is logged which looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pf0cq6d2lmppvq/power.png?dl=0

**Red**: electrical current/power at this moment
**Green**: Accumulated power

**Goal**: Identify cycles and return their starting time and power consumption.

A washing **cycle can be identified** by the connected spikes in the **red line**.
The **power usage** of a single cycle is the difference of accumulated.start_of_cycle and accumulated.end_of_cycle

Can anyone tell me how I would do this? I assume window functions but I never did anything like this..

A data sample can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/311345/data.csv

Comment: please don't provide links to data. put some effort and post it as *text* in the question.

Comment: It is quite a lot of data that is needed to illustrate the problem .. it doesn't make sense if I reduce it to a text that can be posted..

Comment: you can always show some representative sample from your dataset, which will help people answer your question.